# c++: optimize writing to .csv file

Tags: file, csv, optimization, fstream, ofstream

I have this huge array of positive (>=0) integers and in my program I need to print it to a file several times, formatting it as a matrix in .csv

I was wondering what is the most efficient way to do this, since basically my program is spending the most of the time writing it out...

my way is:

```
ofstream fout(to_string(k)+".csv)
if(fout){
   for(unsigned int i; i<NumRows; ++i){
      for(unsigned int j; j<NumCol; ++j
         fout<<array[i*NumCol+j]<<",";
      fout<<array[i*NumCol+NumCol-1]<<"\n";
      };
  }else{.....};
```

Comment: As long as you avoid making any explicit `write` system calls, there's not much you can do to make your code less efficient than whatever you get by using `<<`.  IOW, don't worry about it.  You are IO bound, and changing your code to make you more processor efficient is a waste of time.

Comment: @WilliamPursell what do you think of saving each line in a string (formatted with commas) and then writing the whole string to the file?

Comment: @WilliamPursell is probably right. If you run some stackshots on this, they are probably almost all going to be in something with a name like `flush_buffer`. Any others will most likely be converting a number to characters. The actual appending of characters to the buffer should be miniscule compared to what else it is doing. Stackshots will tell for sure.